# page/feed not working Facebook Graph API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm using `koala gem` and i've an access token , which performs the good when facebook_id is a timeline of a user . but in case of ,if, it's facebook page itself ,then it returns nothing . I've gone through with [Acting LIke a page](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Acting-as-a-Page) and some other links also but no gain . Can any one tell that why `page/feed` method not working in case of pages. I've tried the `page_id/posts` also but all in vain . Major thing is that `get_page_access_token` in the `koala` given doc [Acting LIke a page](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Acting-as-a-Page) also not working . and i'm using page token which graph API has given . I'm sure that `page_token` given by the Graph API explorer is correct because whenever i make `@page_graph.get_object(fb_id)` it returns me basic data of page

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the manage_pages permission on the User Access Token you're using to get a Page Access Token? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/managing

Comment: @corvuszero i marked all the permissions